# Git-Diff vs. Git-log? What's the difference?

Tags: git

I'm a little bit confused about Git. When I'm looking through the manual it appears the Diff is included in the Git-log manual. Also when I'm looking at tutorials and stuff, I find that Git log does much of the same stuff git-diff does. Is Git-Diff's functionality just a subset of Git-log?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`git log` can use `git diff` to display each change in the history. `git log` is for displaying a set of revisions, potentially including the diff between each revision and its parent, while `git diff` is used for displaying the difference between any two revisions in your repository.

`git diff` can also be used to display diffs between the current working copy and the staging area (also known as the "index"), and diffs between the staging area and a revision in your repository, usually HEAD, while `git log` will only ever show committed code.

So, they do have a bit of overlap, but neither one is a subset of the other. `git log` uses `git diff` for some forms of its display, and thus has the same options for setting how it calls `git diff`.

Comment: a much better answer than mine.